# Predicate with arguments and predicate without arguments in alloy

Tags: alloy

I saw the following definition in a book:

```
pred show(b: Book){
  some b.addr
}
```

where

```
abstract sig Name, Addr {}
sig Book { addr: Name lone -> lone Addr }
```

After playing with the Alloy analyzer, I realized this is the same as

```
pred show(){
  some b:Book | some b.addr
}
```

I was curious what is the advantage of specifying Book as an argument, and not use the second approach using quantifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Using or not using arguments to predicates is not an 'approach' it has different semantics. If you include `some b` in your predicate you can't use `all b` outside of it...

For example:

```
sig Addr {}

sig Book {
    addr: Addr
}

pred show {
    some b:Book | some b.addr
}

pred show'[b:Book] {
    some b.addr
}

check { show }

// These are not possible without an argument to show'
check { all b:Book | show'[b] }
check { some b:Book | show'[b] }
check { no b:Book | show'[b] }
```

Comment: The second `check`'s assertion is, indeed, equivalent to `show`.

Comment: I'll also add that using arguments allows you to (more easily) verify important properties. E.g.: correctness and consistency of operations.